# How can I make db_query SELECT LIKE case insensitive?

Tags: database

I'm querying for an email address where I can't force the case of the search term or the data in the table. It's an API thing.

How can I convert this query to be case insensitive?

```
$results = db_query(
 'SELECT email_address
  FROM email_address_table
  WHERE (email_address LIKE :mail)',
  array(':mail' => '%' . db_like($mail) . '%')
)->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to accomplish this is to compare a lower-case version of you search string against a the lower-cased variant in the table. See below for an example using [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) and [LOWER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower):

```
$mail = strtolower($mail);

$results = db_query(
 'SELECT email_address
  FROM email_address_table
  WHERE (LOWER(email_address) LIKE :mail)',
  array(':mail' => '%' . db_like($mail) . '%')
)->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Points! One corollary bit of info that came up. When doing a string comparison on a blob explicitly convert it to a string ala LOWER(CONVERT( @string_variable USING latin1)). Or whichever charset works for you.